# paypal payment method not coming up in checkout drupal ubercart

Tags: paypal, drupal-7, ubercart, express-checkout

I am using Drupal 7 with ubercart. I am using Paypal Express checkout for my payment method.

I am able to see "Checkout with paypal button" in view cart page.[image]

But When I click Checkout button, it takes me to the order submission page. Here I cannot see Paypal in Payment Method section.

[image]

I don't know what options to check. I do not have any other payment method.
Do I need to change any code in module? what should I do?

Also I am able to place order in system as it is not going to paypal on order submit.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to pay with paypal then select another Payment option , and that option is "

**PayPal Website Payments Standard** " , because that checkout with paypal in Ubercart Product is also not

working with me. so i have used **PayPal Website Payments Standard** and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Having spent quite a lot of time trying to make the PayPal Express Checkout working, I thought I should share my findings for anyone who runs into the same issue.

Solution found here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2099557

So to make the PayPal Express Checkout working

- enable uc_credit and uc_paypal modules;
- on Payment methods settings (/admin/store/settings/payment) enable "Paypal Express Checkout" and "Credit card"
- configure settings for "PayPal Express Checkout" (admin/store/settings/payment/method/paypal_ec)
- on Credit card settings (/admin/store/settings/payment/method/credit), select PayPal Website Payment Pro as the Default gateway
- and finally upgrade your PayPal account to Pro. If on Sandbox account, go to Accounts, click Profile on your BUSINESS account and click "Upgrade" on the Account Details window.